# QGIS: determining the ice divide on a small ice cap

Tags: qgis, watershed, flow-map, flow-direction

I have a GeoTIFF file with the surface elevation of a small ice cap. The ice cap has an ice divide, where the ice diverges. Part of it flows towards a glacier in the north, the other part flows towards the south. In QGIS, I have transformed the surface aspect into arrows (the surface aspect denotes the direction of ice flow) to get a clear view on where this ice divide might be (where the ice diverges). I think it works a bit the same like a watershed.

How can I quantify the surface area of the ice cap that flows towards the glacier in the north? Or turn it into a polygon? I put below an image with a rough line drawn by myself of where I think more or less the divide is. How can I get this done?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Reclassify](https://fivequestionz.home.blog/2020/02/08/how-to-reclassify-a-raster-layer-in-qgis/) your aspect raster.  [Here is a link to the values](https://gisgeography.com/aspect-map/) in an aspect.   raster.  Reclassify such that the resulting reclassified raster has values for 1 for all north facing pixels, and 2 for all south facing pixels as determined by you.  If you need a polygon as your result then consider [converting the reclassified raster to a polygon](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/raster_to_vector.html).

If this approach does not work because of the oddities of the directions of the aspects (for example, some pixel point south but then contribute to the norther glacier) you should generate a flow accumulation surface and generate a resulting watershed.  The resulting watershed can then be polygonized.  [See this tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/processing/hydro.html).

Comment: Yes, but there are also some initially southeast flowing pixels (look at the left below corner) that eventually flow into the northern glacier, so this approach wouldn't work.

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your comment.